# Android application restarts without any expection and logcat message on onresume mostly

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

I am working on shopping application. I am facing a strange problem. Application keeps restarting itself after sometime on resuming some activity. It's happens mostly on 4.2.2 and some devices of 4.3 . Application working very well on s3 , s4 and s5. But having problem with devices of htc mostly. I also checked the heap size and free memory using MAT. In my application I am also doing system.gc() in almost every method.When application restarts I haven't see any error or exception in logcat also. Can anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Do you have code that suppresses printing Throwables? This is usually related to usage of `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`
Why are you calling gc()?

Comment: no don't have any code like this. And just calling system.gc() to collect the garbage of each method.

Comment: offtopic note, this is not how GC works, actually what i know is that you should not call GC, instead enhance your code.